# SQL for selecting recurring transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

my table structure in sql server db is as below

```
id  field1  field2  field3  field4  field5  field6  field7
1   x       10      abc     x       x       x       x
2   x       10      abc     x1      x6      x2      x2
3   x       10      xyz     x2      x6      x3      x3
4   x       20      abc     x3      x7      x4      x4
5   x       20      abc     x4      x8      x5      x5
6   x       10      abc     x5      x9      x6      x6
```

as per my biz logic, ids 1,2,4,5 as recurring orders as they have same values in field1, field2 and field3.  what HIGH PERFORMANCE query do i write to retrieve only those orders which are recurring.  ie, i want output as below

```
id  field1  field2  field3  field4  field5  field6  field7
1   x       10      abc     x       x       x       x
2   x       10      abc     x1      x6      x2      x2
4   x       20      abc     x3      x7      x4      x4
5   x       20      abc     x4      x8      x5      x5
```

1. No orders with id 3 and 6 as they are unique.
2. all fields should be in the output

This is equivalent to identifying duplicate records, but in the output i want the duplicate and the original records.

Also, this table has millions of records, so don't want to use temp tables and group by commands.  i think i need to use partition over.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COUNT OVER`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        cnt = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY field1, field2, field3)
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    id, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7
FROM Cte
WHERE cnt  > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM #Table T JOIN ( SELECT field1 ,  field2 ,  field3
FROM #Table GROUP BY field1 ,  field2 ,  field3 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) A ON A.field1 = T.field1 AND A.field2 = T.field2 AND A.field3 = T.field3
```